# Resetting network interfaces when waking up from suspension

Tags: networking, suspend

I carry my laptop in "suspended" state and routinely use the Ethernet port. When I move it, the usual sequence of event is: suspend, unplug all the wires (power, Ethernet), put in bag, move, take from bag, plug in the wires, and wake up.

In the new location, the Ethernet connection is non-functional until I un-plug/re-plug the cable (or stop/start the interface in the network manager). I think that somehow the system doesn't check for changes that occurred while suspended. I have similar problems with the Wifi interface (which is even more surprising, because the SSIDs is different...).

So I'm looking for a way to reset all these interfaces:

- either as root (/etc/init.d/networking restart ?) but how can I execute this on wake up?
- as a plain user (but I can't find an adequate notification, nor do I know a user-level command for this).

Any ideas?

Running Kubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a script on: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d

Mark it as executable with the commands you want to execute, and configured with the condition resume.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
        resume)
            /etc/init.d/networking restart
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the scripts that run on resume. Doing a bit of preliminary exploration, it seems that the network manager is also doing things on resume so I'll check this first.